# angular2: how to get Full path on CanLoad guard while maintaining redirect url

Tags: angular2-routing

I am using angular 2.4 version and router version "^3.4.10".

I am trying to handle redirect url using auth guard service.

When user hit url 'domain/assignment/3/detail' and if user is not login then user redirected to 'domain/login' page. 
and when user successfully login in to system then redirected to  'domain/assignment/3/detail' previous url which user tries to access.

I have implemented CanLoad guard on assignment module. so when user tries to access url 'domain/assignment/3/detail' and if user is not login, url stores into redirectUrl property of authservice (this.authService.redirectUrl).

so here is the issue comes in my case. i am not able to get full path of the url which user hit. 
i am getting 'assignment' instead 'assignment/3/detail' within CanLoad guard.
how can i get full path so that i can redirect user to proper path within CanLoad guard.

**CanLoad:**

```
 canLoad(route: Route): boolean {

            let url = `/${route.path}`; // here i got url path 'assignment' instead 'assignment/3/detail'

            return this.checkLogin(url);
        }
```

**Main routing** app.routes.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
{
    path: 'assignment',
    loadChildren: './assignment/assignment.module#AssignmentModule',
    canLoad: [AuthGuard]
},
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }];
```

**Assignment routing:** assignment-routing.ts

```
       const assignmentRoutes: Routes = [
        {
            path: '',
            component: AssignmentComponent,
            canActivate: [AuthGuard]
            children: [
                {
                    path: '',
                    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
                    children: [
                        {
                            path: ':assignmentId/detail', component: AssignmentDetailComponent,
                            canActivate: [AuthGuard]

                        }
                      ]
                  }]
         }];
```

AuthGuard: auth-gurad.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    CanActivate, Router,
    ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    RouterStateSnapshot,
    CanActivateChild,
    NavigationExtras,
    CanLoad, Route
} from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanLoad {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        let url: string = state.url;
        return this.checkLogin(url);
    }

    canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        return this.canActivate(route, state);
    }

    canLoad(route: Route): boolean {

        let url = `/${route.path}`; // here i got url path 'assignment' instead 'assignment/3/detail'

        return this.checkLogin(url);
    }



     checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
            if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
                if(this.authService.redirectUrl!=null){
                    let redirectUrl = this.authService.redirectUrl;
                    this.authService.redirectUrl = null;
                    this.this.router.navigate([redirectUrl]);
                }
                return true;
                }

        // Store the attempted URL for redirecting
        this.authService.redirectUrl = url;

        // Navigate to the login page 
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have this exact same problem. These issues are related

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17359
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12411

And they even have an open PR about this which hasn't been merged yet

- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13127

The workaround for now seems to be to replace the `canLoad` method with the `canActivate`, there you can have access to the full path, the bad thing of course is that you're loading the module

Edit: Also for you Assignment routing, there's no need to call `canActivate` for each child route. Have it defined on the parent route should apply the guard for all child routes.

Comment: Thanks Edwin for your suggestions and answer.

Answer (score 11):

If you look the signature of the [canLoad method](https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad), there is is a second parameter `segments` which you can use to generate the url.

```
canLoad(route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean
```

You can generate the full path using following code:

```
canLoad(route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]): boolean {

  const fullPath = segments.reduce((path, currentSegment) => {
    return `${path}/${currentSegment.path}`;
  }, '');

  console.log(fullPath);

}
```

Note: With this method you will get the full path, but you will not get any query parameters.

Comment: which version of `@angular/router` was added, I'm on 6.02 version and the method signature is `canLoad(route: Route)`

Comment: This feature was introduced at version 7.0.0.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#700-2018-10-18

Comment: Is there a way to find the query parameters as well? I've tried to look at `segment.parameters` and `segment.parametersMap` but they seem to be empty.

Comment: This does not give you full path if you have child routes and sub modules.

Answer (score 5):

This workaround from this [reply](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17359#issuecomment-584776004) on the github issue worked very well for me.

```
export class AuthnGuard implements CanLoad {
  constructor(private authnService: AuthnService, private router: Router) { }

  canLoad( ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
    let url = '/';

    if (navigation) {
      url = navigation.extractedUrl.toString();
    }
    this.authnService.storeRedirectUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is another *temporary* workaround instead of replacing `canLoad` with `canActivate`:

You can store the url via `redirectUrl = location.pathname` and redirect later via `this.router.navigateByUrl(redirectUrl);`. Of course, if you work on a subpath (like `domain`) you have to adjust the `pathname` a little bit.

Comment: Attention! `canLoad` and `canActivate` behave different. `canLoad` prevents a module from beeing loaded. `canActivate` only prevents from beeing viewed but all it's files would be downloaded. This can have a performance impact if you have a huge lazy loaded module for example.

Answer (score 3):

In Angular 9, following [reply](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17359#issuecomment-419727276) worked for me.

My code

```js
export class AuthGuard implements CanLoad {
    constructor(private router: Router, private loginService: LoginService) { }

    canLoad( ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        if (this.loginService.isLoggedIn()) return true;

        this.router.events.pipe(first(_ => _ instanceof NavigationCancel)).subscribe((event: NavigationCancel) => {

            this.router.navigate(['/login'], {
                    queryParams: {
                        redirectTo: event.url
                    }
            });
        });
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

information available on

```
this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extractedUrl
```

relates to this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30633

Answer (score 0):

I'm using

```
this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extractedUrl.toString()
```

to access the full route, since

```
segments.reduce((path, currentSegment) => {
  return `${path}/${currentSegment.path}`;
}, '')
```

will not provide the full path if you have nested routes (only child routes).