# Angular 9 and Ionic Redirect to previous page when auth Guard sends user to login or sign up

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm working on an app. I have a cylinders page that serves as the homepage. I passed a dynamic routing when user clicks a size of cylinder to view its detail in another page. This Cylinder detail page has an auth guard which takes user to login or sign up. Upon successful sign in or login, I want user to go back to the selected cylinder size detail page it was redirected from initially. I have tried to integrate answers i've seen on stack but not working. I hope I can get this over with with an explanation on how it was solved too. I will attach my source codes.

**auth.guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanLoad, Route, UrlSegment, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { take, tap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanLoad {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canLoad(
    route: Route,
    segments: UrlSegment[]): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
      return this.authService.userIsAuthenticated.pipe(
        take(1),
        switchMap(isAuthenticated => {
          if (!isAuthenticated) {
            return this.authService.autoLogin();
          } else {
            return of(isAuthenticated);
          }
        }),
        tap((isAuthenticated) => {
          if (!isAuthenticated) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth');
          }
        })
      ); // boolean
  }
}
```

**auth.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { LoadingController, AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AuthService, AuthResponseData } from './auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-auth',
  templateUrl: './auth.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auth.page.scss'],
})
export class AuthPage implements OnInit {
  // property
  isLoading = false;
  isLogin = true;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    private alertCtrl: AlertController
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  authenticate(email: string, password: string) {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.loadingCtrl
      .create({ keyboardClose: true, message: 'Logging you in...' })
      .then((loadingEl) => {
        loadingEl.present();
        let authObs: Observable<AuthResponseData>;
        if (this.isLogin) {
          authObs = this.authService.login(email, password);
        } else {
          // if we are not logged in but signing up
          authObs = this.authService.signUp(email, password);
        }
        authObs.subscribe(
          (resData) => {
            console.log(resData);
            this.isLoading = false;
            loadingEl.dismiss();
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/cylinders');
          },
          (errRes) => {
            console.log(errRes);
            loadingEl.dismiss();
            const code = errRes.error.error.message;
            let message = 'Could not sign you up, please try again';
            if (code === 'EMAIL_EXISTS') {
              message = 'This email address already exists!';
            } else if (code === 'EMAIL_NOT_FOUND') {
              message = 'E-Mail address could not be found.';
            } else if (code === 'INVALID_PASSWORD') {
              message = 'Your password is incorrect';
            }
            this.showAlert(message);
          }
        );
      });
  }

  onSwitchAuthMode() {
    this.isLogin = !this.isLogin;
  }

  // switch our authentication mode based on state. we invert. if its false its true if its true its false
  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (!form.valid) {
      return;
    }
    // IF YOU HAVE A VALID FORM THEN WE MAKE A POSITIVE IF CHECK AND PROCEED TO THE BELOW
    const email = form.value.email; // from the name given to our forms
    const password = form.value.password;

    // we check if authenticated and forward email and password
    this.authenticate(email, password);
    form.reset();
  }

  // SHOW ERROR MESSAGE TO USERS
  private showAlert(message: string) {
    this.alertCtrl
      .create({
        header: 'Authentication failed',
        // tslint:disable-next-line: object-literal-shorthand
        message: message,
        buttons: ['Okay'],
      })
      .then((alertEl) => {
        alertEl.present();
      });
  }
}
```

**cylinders.page.html** holds my list of cylinders which takes user to a cylinder-detail page when clicked to view the detail of a cylinder but this **cylinder-detail page** has an auth guard.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <!-- HAMBURGER MENU BUTTON -->
    <ion-buttons slot="start" contentId="main">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>

    <ion-title>Select Gas to Refill</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>

    <!-- SUCCESSFUL LOGIN OR SIGNUP SHOULD TAKE USER TO THE SPECIFIED ROUTE BELOW  -->

    <ion-item *ngFor="let cylinder of cylinders" [routerLink]="['./', cylinder.size]">
      <ion-avatar slot="start">
        <ion-img [src]="cylinder.imageUrl"></ion-img>
      </ion-avatar>

      <ion-label color="primary"> {{ cylinder.size }} </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'cylinders', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'cylinders',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./cylinders/cylinders.module').then(
            m => m.CylindersPageModule
          )
      },
      {
// BELOW IS THE DYNAMIC ROUTING WHEN USER SHOULD NAVIGATE AFTER AUTH
        path: ':cylinderSize',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./cylinders/cylinder-detail/cylinder-detail.module').then(
            m => m.CylinderDetailPageModule
          ),
        canLoad: [AuthGuard]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'checkout',
    loadChildren: () => import('./checkout/checkout.module').then( m => m.CheckoutPageModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

So for the use case you have, where you want your user to "resume" to the initially requested page after auth is successful the high level logic of implementation can be achieved this way:

- in your auth guard when redirecting user to auth page you need to capture their full "return URL" and pass it along, such that login/auth page had access to it.
- then after successful auth, you use that returnURL and help user navigate there

If you want to stick to canLoad (that prevents not just access but loading of the module), there is a way to do it:

1.Update your canLoad method to pass the return URL when navigating to auth page:

```
// **inside** canLoad guard obtain full path (returnURL) this way as suggested in this answer (segments is one of the arguments canLoad method receives): 

const returnUrl = segments.reduce((path, currentSegment) => {
  return `${path}/${currentSegment.path}`;
}, '');


// then instead of this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth'), do ~this:

this.router.navigate(['auth'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: this.router.routerState.snapshot.url }});
```

2.Now in your auth service, after successful auth you direct user to the previously attempted page:

```
// instead of this.router.navigateByUrl('/cylinders'), do ~this:
let returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/cylinders';
this.router.navigateByUrl(returnUrl)
```

For the above to work you need to import ActivatedRoute etc.

Hope you can take it from here.

Also see similar question and answer here: [angular2: how to get Full path on CanLoad guard while maintaining redirect url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44538256/angular2-how-to-get-full-path-on-canload-guard-while-maintaining-redirect-url)

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking out time to go through those lines of code. I tried to integrate the explanation you gave. In number 2, you mean auth.page.ts I presume? Also, I imported activatedRoute in auth.page.ts but nothing seems to work. Still takes me back to cylinders page upon login or sign up. Are there other imports aside activatedRoute?

Comment: After the auth process, my url shows the passed URL in routing service but does not navigate to the cylinder-detail page rather it remains on the auth page and shows this. http://localhost:8100/auth?returnUrl=:cylinderSize

Comment: @user9154750 so based on your answer it seems like where you want to send user is something like this: "/cylinders/100" (100 here is whatever cylinderSize resolves to). So for your case you need to ensure you pass to auth.page.ts already resolved full path not just local one (:cylinderSize). I ll update my answer a bit

Comment: try this.router.navigate(['auth'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: this.router.routerState.snapshot.url }}); and let me know what URL you get?

Comment: Hello Sergey, yes you get it right. intend to navigate back to (:cylinderSize) normally, once auth is successful, URL should look like localhost:8100/cylinders/10kg. I updated the auth.guard.ts file as you proposed and got this in the URL http://localhost:8100/auth?returnUrl=%2Fcylinders

Comment: OK ill find time to recreate your case and will fix the answer unless someone else answers sooner. Should be not hard

Comment: updated the answer. Also found similar issue and linked it as well. Try the approach with segments.reduce - to obtain full URL in canLoad the way described and let me know how it works for you - are you able to get full URL in your console.log

Comment: I console.log the returnUrl and got the selected cylinder item in the console and in the URL on auth page, it shows the 'cylinders' page as the page to redirect to after auth is successful instead of going to the size captured as shown in console.log I might be unable to make more comments due to limitations here and new to StackOverflow so no live chat enabled yet too.